# how to force user to select drop down list item first before continue next in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

http://www.tgv.com.my/

for example of this website, the quick ticket session.
i need to force users to select a movie first before select the Cinema

Comment: well, you can hide the cinema selection and add it after the movie has been selected. Or you can leave the list of cinemas empty until the movie is selected and then fill it in

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Your question is totally unclear. And honestly, seems a little bit spam to me since it includes only a website link. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: how to hide the cinema selection and add it after the movie has been selected?

Comment: @KuokLoongChen You probably want to populate the cinema drop down after a movie has been selected right, not only hide/show it. To show only those movies available at the selected cinema?

Comment: @Magnus yes this is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some jQuery magic to do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#ddlSelectCinema').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ddlSelectSession').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

This code will disable the "Select Cinema" and "Select Session" drop downs. Then you need an event handler on the drop downs:

```
$(function() {
    $('#ddlSelectMovie').change(function() {
        $('#ddlSelectCinema').prop('disabled', false);
    });
    $('#ddlSelectCinema').change(function() {
        $('#ddlSelectSession').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

This will not hide it, but it will disable them. You might want to also add a CSS class called 'disabled' or something and apply and remove that class as you disable/enable the. This way you can style the drop downs and make them look disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
 comboboxCinema.Visible = False;
```

and on movie selected index change make cinema combo box visible to true

```
  private void comboboxMovie_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    comboboxCinema.Visible = True;
  }
```